# Aplicação angular não roda localmente no IE?

Tags: angular, front-end, internet-explorer

Segue a **imagem** do erro no *browser* (**Internet Explorer v.11)**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DETALHE: nos outros navegadores (**Chrome** e **Firefox**) funciona (roda/carrega).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11) vc tem que descomentar o arquivo polyfills.ts por padrao dentro da pasta src

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: OK, vou verificar.

Comment: OK, deu certo @Eduardo Vargas, agora se tu tivesse um tutorial para me passar sobre "rotas", por que estou tomando um pau, eu agradeceria.

Comment: Cara esses dias eu respondi um post sobre rotas talvez te ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297751/componente-filho-de-outro-componente-n%C3%A3o-carrega/297863#297863 mas o melhor e a documentação mesmo. Ou então faz outra pergunta ai. Se vc nao fizer lazy-loading não e tao complicado, so lembre de colocar o numero certo de <router-outlets> tbm

Comment: OK, so pedi pra vc, e n me leve a mal é por q meu inglês é péssimo e na net n tem tutorias ótimos e vi q vc é especialista em Angular. Mas fico feliz e agradecido mesmo assim!